# how to use same style for image imported in code

Tags: css

I used image in my project imported in .css file and I changed it to have it in code. Unfortunately the style doesn't work the same way.
Is there any easy way how to fix them?

```
<div class="image" />


    
.image {
        background: url('./../images/example.jpg') no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        height: 530px;
    }
```

to

```
    <div>
        <img class="image"
             src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/example.jpg`}
             alt="Example"/>
    </div>

.image {
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 530px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a typo in your example code..? `...className="image"...` should be `...class="image"...`. And yes, the image will work differently as an image and as a div background. You could add the `background-image` dynamically to a `style` attribute if you want.

Comment: yes, it is class not className :)

Comment: and how  can do that? my project is written in react

Comment: See answer(s) below.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the style to the img tag:

```css
img {
  height: 530px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
img {
  height: 530px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="image"
    src="https://via.placeholder.com/200"
    alt="Example"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Put the image URL in a style attribute

Your CSS code can stay mostly the same. See below.
The trick is to not write an `img` tag, but give the div a `style` attribute with a `background-image`:

```html
<div class="image"
     style="background-image:url({`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/example.jpg`});">
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 530px;
}
```

Here is a demonstration with an example image:

```css
.image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 530px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="image" style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/200);">
</div>
```